# python random number generator for long list of numbers

Tags: python, random

I was wondering if anyone could help me write a better program. My goal is to make a random number generatorm but it has very specific perameters. I need to find a random number that looks for a random number for unit numbers in a housing compley. the parameters are between 101-112, 114-125, 128-149, 201-230, 232-263, 265-280 and 300-305. I made a list with every number and then called the random number function, but I was just wondering if there was an easier way or a more concise way to make this program. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make sure that your choice is equiprobable, your could start by choosing among your ranges with weights equal to the number of values in each range. [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) allows you to specify weights.

You can then simply choose any value in the selected range:

```
import random

def random_in_ranges(ranges):
    weights = [end - start + 1 for start, end in ranges]
    range_ = random.choices(ranges, weights=weights)[0]
    return random.randint(*range_)




ranges = [(101,112), (114,125), (128,149), (201,230), (232,263), (265,280), (300,305)]
print(random_in_ranges(ranges))
# 262
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
flat_num = random.choise(flats)
```

if you have your number in some Iterable struct

or

you can random range and then select from selected range if you have just a numbers like this:

```
flat_num = random.randint(
  *random.choice(
    [(101,112),(114,125),(128,149),(201-230),(232-263),(300-305)]
  )
)
```

Comment: Why is it often happens with me - why somebody minused my answer?

Comment: I like your answer so upvoted.

Comment: The choice won't be equiprobable at all. Getting 301 is 5 times more probable than 201.